# RVCT to ARM GCC porting(__uadd8)

Tags: c, gcc, arm, gnu

I was doing porting of armcc compiler to ARM GNU GCC , I pretty much figured out everything but I am stuck at this point :

A code is using something like this :

```
unsigned int add_bytes(unsigned int val1, unsigned int val2)
{
  unsigned int res;

    res = __uadd8(val1,val2); /* res[7:0] = val1[7:0] + val2[7:0]
                                 res[15:8] = val1[15:8] + val2[15:8]
                                 res[23:16] = val1[23:16] + val2[23:16]
                                 res[31:24] = val1[31:24] + val2[31:24]
                               */
    return res;
}
```

__uadd8 is RVCT specific , Is there something equivalent provided by GCC or how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GCC` doesn't provide intrinsics for `ARMv6` SIMD instructions. However you can define your own `__UADD8` like below.

```
__attribute__( ( always_inline ) ) static __inline__ uint32_t __UADD8(uint32_t op1, uint32_t op2)
{
  uint32_t result;

  __asm__ volatile ("uadd8 %0, %1, %2" : "=r" (result) : "r" (op1), "r" (op2) );
  return(result);
}
```

This is from one of the [CMSIS header files](http://www.das-labor.org/svn/microcontroller/src-stm32f4xx/serialUSB/Libraries/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4_simd.h). I didn't test it myself but including that file might fix every other v6 intrinsics. At worst you may need to do some copy-pasting.